# How to use datalist inside dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making dynamic table with adding rows and every row have datalist. The problem is that on first row it shows text, but on other rows it shows integer from Value. And I want to show text from data-text.

Check my code on: https://codepen.io/aleksandar095/pen/eYmqYVO

Maybe I still don't get it how id works. Problem might be in js code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 2;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function() {

      counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";

      cols += '<td><input list="animals" class="form-control" id="animal'+counter+'" name="animal"><datalist id="animals"><option data-text="cat" value="1">Text 1</option><option data-text="dog" value="2">Text 2</option><option data-text="fish" value="3">Text 3</option></datalist></td>';


      cols += '<td><button type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #fff;"></i></button></td>';
      newRow.append(cols);
      $("table.order-list").append(newRow);

      $("#animal" + counter).bind("select", function() {
        if ($('#animals').find('option').length) {
          if ($('option[value=' + this.value + ']').length > 0) {
            $("#animal" + counter).val($('option[value=' + this.value + ']').data("text"));
          }
        }
      })

      counter++;
    });
```

Please check my full code on codepen.

Comment: your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Do you want to show the text instead of value?

Comment: I want to show text in textbox instead value. Check CodePen, You will see that first row works as I want, when I add more rows it not working well

Answer (score 0):

Just changing these lines should help you output your contructed html.

```
var newRow = '<tr>'

var cols = '<td><input list="animals" class="form-control" id="animal'+counter+'" name="animal"><datalist id="animals"><option data-text="cat" value="1">Text 1</option><option data-text="dog" value="2">Text 2</option><option data-text="fish" value="3">Text 3</option></datalist></td>';

cols += '<td><button type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #fff;"></i></button></td>';
newRow += cols;

$("table.order-list").append(newRow);
```

Or, even simpler:

```
let newRow = '<tr>'  
newRow += '<td><input list="animals" class="form-control" id="animal'+counter+'" name="animal"><datalist id="animals"><option data-text="cat" value="1">Text 1</option><option data-text="dog" value="2">Text 2</option><option data-text="fish" value="3">Text 3</option></datalist></td>';
newRow += '<td><button type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #fff;"></i></button></td>';

$("table.order-list").append(newRow);
```